# Who is ServerFault Valued Associate #0000004?

Tags: discussion, blog

Either blog entry about *ServerFault Valued Associate #0000004!* isn't tagged `stuff` or there is no info about this person or that person does not exist.

Anyway, when I [browse serverfault.com's blog for `staff` category](http://blog.serverfault.com/category/staff/), I don't see even a bit about him/her (there's a gap between #0000003 and #0000005).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be [Bart Silverstrim](https://serverfault.com/users/13647/bart-silverstrim), he was hired after Pete.

Comment: Good question, why he isn't listed on blog with `stuff` tag?

Comment: He was hired by Fog Creek... Not sure if that still counts